# How to display foreign key value from a model to a cascaded dropdown list in mvc5?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm still new to mvc5 and had very little knowledge with javascript. I know that my cascading works but I'm having trouble with the display part. What I want to do is have 2 dropdown list. 1 containing all customer names and the 2nd will have a list of their pending transactions. Basically 1st dropdown will have customer names while the 2nd will have video titles. Please check my code where I did wrong. Why I can't display the video titles. BTW I tried other properties in my transactions and I can display them. That's how I know that my cascading is not the problem.

Models

```
//Transaction Model
TransactionID { get; set; }
public int CustomerID { get; set; }
public virtual Customers CustomerName { get; set; }
public int VideoID { get; set; }
public virtual Videos Videos { get; set; }
public int Quantity { get; set; }
[ReadOnly(true)]
public DateTime? TransactionDate { get; set; }
[ReadOnly(true)]
public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
[ReadOnly(true)]
public Decimal Cost { get; set; }
[ReadOnly(true)]
public String ReturnStatus { get; set;}

//Customers Model
public int CustomerID { get; set; }
public string CustomerName { get; set; }
public string CustomerAddress { get; set; }
public string CustomerContact { get; set; }

//Video Model
public int VideoID { get; set; }
public string VideoTitle { get; set; }
public int CategoryID { get; set; }
public virtual Category VideoCategory { get; set; }
[Range(0,99)]
public int VideoIn { get; set; }
[Range(0,99)]
public int VideoOut { get; set; }
```

Conroller

```
public ActionResult CustomerList()
{
   var customers = db.Customers.OrderBy(x => x.CustomerID).ToList();
    if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return Json(new SelectList(
                    customers,
                    "CustomerID",
                    "CustomerName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                    );
    }
    return View(customers);
}

public ActionResult Transact(int cusId)
{
    var transact = db.Transactions
                     .Where(x => x.CustomerID == cusId)
                     .Where(s => s.ReturnStatus == "FALSE").ToList();
    if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return Json(new SelectList(
                        transact,
                        "TransactionID",
                        "VideoTitle"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                    );
    return View(transact);
}
```

Comment: are you getting value transact variable?

Comment: Your `Transaction` model does not even contain a property named `VideoTitle`. And you have not even shown the view code. And return an anonymous object in the `JsonResult`, not a `SelectList` (there is no point passing the extra values of `SelectListItem` to the client.

Comment: @LateshtClick.com yes bro. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for the later info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out a solution after hours of trial an error. What I did is I added a join in my query.

```
var transact = db.Transactions
                        .Where(x => x.CustomerID == cusId)
                        .Where(s => s.ReturnStatus == "FALSE")
                        .Join(db.Videos,
                        v => v.VideoID,
                        t => t.VideoID,
                        (transaction, videos) => new { 
                        TransactionID = transaction.TransactionID,
                        VideoTitle = videos.VideoTitle }).ToList();
```